# Make first letter of string lower case in golang

Tags: go

I'd like to de-capitalise the first letter of a given string. I've looked into the ***cases*** and ***strings*** packages, the closest I found was `cases.Title`

```
cases.Title(language.Und, cases.NoLower).String("MyString")
```

Which can take in a second argument `cases.someThing` however with this, I cannot find a way need to achieve lowering just the first character.

PS. Using go version 1.20

Comment: There's no generic format for "lowercase first letter of a string". Why not just take the first letter and change it to lowercase?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm trying to take a string "HelloJim" and convert it to "helloJim"

Comment: Yes, take the first letter ("rune") and lowercase it. There is no generic function for this, because it's not something you normally do.

Comment: e.g. `myString = strings.ToLower(myString[:1]) + myString[1:]`

Comment: @Gavin: that will fail for any multi-byte unicode characters, which is why I mentioned "rune".

Comment: @JimB Ah, you're right. Maybe something like `runes := []rune(myString); myString = strings.ToLower(string(runes[0])) + string(runes[1:])` would be better: https://go.dev/play/p/_JMeOMuusgq

Comment: Or just use `unicode.ToLower()` rather than repeatedly converting to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

https://goplay.tools/snippet/c7b_OZ19oMC

```
func firstLetterToLower(s string) string {

    if len(s) == 0 {
        return s
    }

    r := []rune(s)
    r[0] = unicode.ToLower(r[0])

    return string(r)
}
```

Comment: Go was designed and implemented to support efficient programs. A simple Go benchmark (`"Hello World"` and `"hello World"`) shows `222.2 ns/op` and `2 allocs/op` for your function and `50.28 ns/op` and `1 allocs/op` for my function. For a string where the first character is already lowercase (`"hello World"`) the benchmark shows `110.9 ns/op` and `1 allocs/op` for your function and `6.00 ns/op` and `0` allocs/op for my function.

Answer (score 3):

In Go, write a simple and efficient function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func firstToLower(s string) string {
    r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s)
    if r == utf8.RuneError && size <= 1 {
        return s
    }
    lc := unicode.ToLower(r)
    if r == lc {
        return s
    }
    return string(lc) + s[size:]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(firstToLower("Hello World"))
    fmt.Println(firstToLower("hello World"))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Vtx75XKWJsD

```
hello World
hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution without using `unicode` library for ASCII latin characters. Since byte value of lower case of these characters 32 more compared to upper case this should work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(toLowerFirstC("Hello World"))
}

func toLowerFirstC(s string) string {
    
    if len(s) != 0 && (s[0] <= 90 && s[0] >= 65) {
        return string(s[0] + 32) + string(s[1:])
    }
    
    return s
}
```

Output:

```
hello World
```

Comment: Go is designed for readability. Don't use "magic" numbers. Go is designed for performance. The earliest tests should exclude the most cases. If the first test is `s[0] >= 'A'` then all uppercase and lowercase letters are included in the second test `s[0] <= 'Z'`. However, if the first test is `s[0] <= 'Z'` then only uppercase letters are included in the second test s[0] >= 'A'. See https://go.dev/play/p/PyRl_1-f72V.

Comment: Since i used && operator the value checking will be stuck at between 'Z' and 'A'. Neither in  first `s[0] <= 'Z'` nor first `s[0] >= 'A'` will include all characters.

Comment: For [Go](https://go.dev/ref/spec) logical operators, the right operand is evaluated conditionally (short-circuited): `&& conditional AND p && q is "if p then q else false"`. Consider all 52 ASCII upper and lower case Latin letters. For your slow version `(b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z')`: `ifA 52 ifZ 52 AandZ 26`, that is, `b >= 'A'` is executed 52 times, `b <= 'Z'` is executed 52 times, and the logical operation is true 26 times. For my fast version `(b <= 'Z' && b >= 'A')`: `ifZ 52 ifA 26 ZandA 26`, that is, b >= 'A' is only executed 26 times. See https://go.dev/play/p/bxU18uB7iqJ.

Comment: thanks for guide. i understood what you mean.